# Keychain passwords suggestions that I can't remember, how do I log in from a different pc

Tags: security, password, keychain, twitter

I hope that I put it right, that you guys understand.

Everywhere I read that Keychain can suggest strong passwords and remember them so I don't have to remember them. Works wonderful.

The thing is, I am scared to do so, because; what will happen if I have to enter one of these sites from a different computer.

Say that I let Keychain come up with a great, strong password for twitter. 
Next time I log on to twitter from an unknown computer, can I still log in with my old password? Or do I actually have to remember the password that Keychain came up with?

The logic thing would be that it actually changes that password, so when I need to enter that website from a different computer, I will still have to use that hard to remember password. Which means I need to keep an extra passwords list somewhere accessible.

I've been looking all over, but I can't seem to find it, so I figured, I'd ask you people.

Can you help me out?

Answer (score 2):

While Keychain Access and the iCloud Keychain is specific to the Mac and iOS, there are other applications such as [1Password](https://agilebits.com/onepassword) and [LastPass](https://lastpass.com/) which have various syncing options (Windows, iOS, Android, Linux, and even web-based) so you would never be without access to your passwords.

Answer (score 1):

If you change your Twitter password, you obviously can't use the old password anymore on other computers.

If your devices are running OS X 10.9 or later or iOS 7.0.3 or later, you can use [iCloud Keychain](http://support.apple.com/kb/HT5813) to sync keychain items.

You can show a password stored in the keychain by opening Keychain Access, selecting the keychain item, pressing command-I, and selecting Show password.

You can also move a keychain to another computer by moving the keychain file (like `~/Library/Keychains/login.keychain`) or by using Migration Assistant.